# Opportunity Product Fields - Names Changed

Tags: opportunity, fields, opportunity-lineitem

I am in the process of merging two Salesforce orgs together.  In one org, opportunity products have fields with names such as "Quantity" and "Total Price".  The other org has those same fields, but they are named "Quantity (enter 1)" and "Total 1st Year Revenue Schedule".  I want Salesforce to show "Quantity" and "Total Price", not the other two.  I have disabled scheduling on the products, thinking this would fix it, but it does not.

What is the cause of this, and how can I go about fixing it?  I cannot find anything on the Internet about the steps to take to change this and am hoping someone here can help.  I am thinking it might have something to do with forecasting, but I don't want to change forecasting stuff without knowing for sure it will fix the problem.  One thing I noticed is that under Setup --> Customize, one org shows "Forecasts" while the other shows "Forecasts (customizable)".  I am not sure if that helps any, but figured I would give the information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked out the Rename tabs and labels section of Setup to see if they were renamed?

Comment: I checked but they are not renamed.  The products are acting differently because a visualforce page is not working either.  This makes me think it is a setting other than simply renaming, but actually provides different functionality.